# Object state not updating in React useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Editing for clarification that this is around a hook as this was marked as a duplicate even though the other question doesn’t use hooks. Another comment had mentioned using `useEffect` so I’ll look into that for now, but if someone could demonstrate with the below or prices additional guidance that would be great!

Original:
So I have a piece of state (`editableSalesperson`) set to an empty object that I want to update with an existing object using `setEditableSalesperson` and pass into my `ModifySalespersons` component to edit it, but the update action isn't actually updating the state.

When I run `editSalesPerson` I see the object getting fed in properly in the console log, but then when it hits `setEditableSalesperson(salesperson);` and I check the state value in the console log in the next line, it is still empty and hasn't changed.

Here's the code. I tried to strip it down to the relevant info, but if you need more info then I can post it.

```
import React from 'react';

function Salespersons(props){
  const [editableSalesperson, setEditableSalesperson] = React.useState({})

  function editSalesPerson(salesperson){
    console.log(salesperson);

    setEditableSalesperson(salesperson);
    console.log(editableSalesperson);
  }

  return (
    <>   
      <ModifySalespersons
        isOpen={isOpen}
        setIsOpen={setIsOpen}
        salesperson={editableSalesperson}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        />
       {/* code here */}
      <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap text-right text-sm leading-5 font-medium">
        <button onClick={ () => editSalesPerson(salesperson) } className="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit</button>
      </td>

    </>
  );
}

export default Salespersons;
```

Comment: It doesn't change immediately, it changes on next render. Keep in mind that it's declared with a `const`, so it can't be reassigned in the current scope anyway

Comment: I was typing an answer and someone closed it and I cant post answer. I use useEffect to overcome this. Also the question linked as duplicate does not use hooks so its really not an answer. This question clearly says `hook` Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks, will look into this. Just posted a clarified question if you’d like to contribute there

Comment: Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/5468463

Comment: Like I said in my first comment, useEffect is the answer which I was posting. Vega's comment above links you to the correct answer for your question :)

Comment: Yup, @Vega ‘s comment looks to cover it. Sore coats if